# Issue getting different types value of self join table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a self join table of population. Population is entered at village level and it should be automatically calculated on Union council(UC), Tehsil and District Level.

I am using .net MVC in this application. Following is my code

enum of population type

```
 public enum UnitType
    {
        Village,
        UC,
        Tehsil,
        Dist
    }
```

population structure, here names of villages, UC, Tehsil and district are added

```
public class Village
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public UnitType UnitType { get; set; }
        public int? ParientId { get; set; }
        public Village Parient { get; set; }
    }
```

Enter population at village level

```
public class Population
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int VillageId { get; set; }
        public Village Village { get; set; }

        public int NoOfPerson { get; set; }
    }


I need the following output result. I can get the village level population but i am confused in getting related totals. Its looks very simple but i think i am not going in right direction.

    POPULATION                  
Code    Name    Type           Population           
1   Chakwal Disttrict   20000   (total population of all tehsils)       
2   Choa    Tehsil          20000   (Tehsil total of two Union Councils)        
3   Dalwal  UC          14300   UC is total of village population       
4   Waulah  Village          9800           
5   DalPur  VIllage          4500           
    Dulmial UC           5700   UC is total of village population       
    Tatral  Village          3400           
    Arar    Village          2300
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the two classes :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<Village> villages = new List<Village>() {
                new Village() { Id = 1, Name = "Chakwal", UnitType = UnitType.Dist},
                new Village() { Id = 2, Name = "Choa", UnitType = UnitType.Tehsil},
                new Village() { Id = 3, Name = "Dalwal", UnitType = UnitType.UC},
                new Village() { Id = 4, Name = "Waulah", UnitType = UnitType.Village},
                new Village() { Id = 5, Name = "DalPur", UnitType = UnitType.Village},
                new Village() { Id = 6, Name = "Dulmial", UnitType = UnitType.UC},
                new Village() { Id = 7, Name = "Tatral", UnitType = UnitType.Village},
                new Village() { Id = 8, Name = "Arar", UnitType = UnitType.Village}
            };
            List<Population> populations = new List<Population>() {
                new Population() { Id = 1, NoOfPerson = 20000},
                new Population() { Id = 2, NoOfPerson = 20000},
                new Population() { Id = 3, NoOfPerson = 14300},
                new Population() { Id = 4, NoOfPerson = 9800},
                new Population() { Id = 5, NoOfPerson = 4500},
                new Population() { Id = 6, NoOfPerson = 5700},
                new Population() { Id = 7, NoOfPerson = 3400},
                new Population() { Id = 8, NoOfPerson = 2300}
            };

            var results = (from v in villages
                           join p in populations on v.Id equals p.Id
                           select new { v = v, p = p }
                          ).ToList();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);

            writer.WriteLine("{0,25}","POPULATION");
            writer.WriteLine("{0,-5}{1,-8}{2,-14}{3,-10}", "Code", "Name", "Type", "Population");

            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                writer.WriteLine("{0,-5}{1,-8}{2,-14}{3,-10}", result.v.Id.ToString(), result.v.Name, result.v.UnitType.ToString(), result.p.NoOfPerson.ToString());
            }
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();

        }
    }
    public enum UnitType
    {
        Village,
        UC,
        Tehsil,
        Dist
    }
    public class Village
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public UnitType UnitType { get; set; }
        public int? ParientId { get; set; }
        public Village Parient { get; set; }
    }
    public class Population
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int VillageId { get; set; }
        public Village Village { get; set; }

        public int NoOfPerson { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: this just list the population and you have added population to UC, Tehsil and distt level. Population should be entered at village level only, all other should be added automatically.

Comment: Entity is a mapping of classes in c# to a database table(s).  There is no such thing a self joining tables.  I entered data into the classes you posted and there is no population property in the village table.  Population is entered into the Population class and the only way of getting both village properties and population properties is by performing a join which is what I did in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for the question

```
var villages = db.Populations.Include(l => l.Village).ToList();

            var ucpop = villages.GroupBy(l => l.UCId).Select(g=> new {
                ucId = g.Key,                
                UcName = db.Villages.Find(g.Key),             
                VillageCount = g.Count(),
                UCPop = g.Sum(l=>l.NoOfPerson),
                villages = g.Where(l=>l.Village.UnitType == UnitType.Village).ToList()
            }).ToList();

            var tehpop = ucpop.GroupBy(l => l.UcName.ParientId).Select(g => new
            {
                tehId = g.Key,
                tehName = db.Villages.Find(g.Key),
                tehCount = g.Count(),
                tehPop = g.Sum(l => l.UCPop),
                uclist = g.Where(l=>l.UcName.UnitType == UnitType.UC).ToList()
            }).ToList();

            var distpop = tehpop.GroupBy(l => l.tehName.ParientId).Select(g => new
            {
                distId = g.Key,
                distName = db.Villages.Find(g.Key),
                distCount = g.Count(),
                distPop = g.Sum(l => l.tehPop),
                tehlist = g.Where(l => l.tehName.UnitType == UnitType.Tehsil).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```